# Excluded files from build is still showing in the sonarqube

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a project with code duplications in jquery intellisense files. So I excluded those files from build and pushed the new package from develop branch to sonarqube. But the code duplication % didn't come down and still the files are showing in the duplicated files list.

I excluded the files using file node and exclude attribute in nuspec file
<file src="scripts** target="scripts" exclude="scripts*.intellisense.js"/>

Comment: Can you please add in the questions what pattern you are giving for `sonar.exclusions` property?

Comment: I excluded the files using file node and exclude attribute in nuspec file <file src="scripts\** target="scripts" exclude="scripts\*.intellisense.js"/>

Comment: could you please try like this `exclude=**/*.js`